# Delete row from a table, deleteRow(id), remove() or use useState () in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with a table that is loaded with the data sent by the REST API, my question more than anything, is if it is good to delete a row  with remove () or deleteRow (index) entering the DOM or I have to manipulate the DOM through a state (useState) for good practice or something like that.

Additional info: I have gotten used to manipulating the DOM directly with pure javascript when making static web pages, but in React I think you have to use props, state, hooks to manipulate the DOM elements or am I wrong? there must be cases I guess.

DOM TRAVERSING

```
export default function App() {
  const data = ['Eli','Smith', 'Jhon']
  const handleDelete = (index,e) => {
      //I can save an ID in <tr> through datasets (data-) 
      //to get it by traversing the DOM when the user clicks and delete it
      //also in my database (API), that's Ok?
      e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.deleteRow(index)
      
  }
  const rows = data.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{item}</td>
        <td><button onClick={e => handleDelete(index,e)}>Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <table>
        {rows}
        </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

That's OK ?

Or do I have to put the rows in a state (useState) and update it by removing the  and re-rendering?

Comment: I think `mapping` all your result in some `div` will be a good price instead of `mapping` them in table :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice is to manage data through state, I would suggest not to do DOM manipulation manually

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(['Eli','Smith', 'Jhon']);
  const handleDelete = (index,e) => {
      setData(data.filter((v, i) => i !== index));
  }
  const rows = data.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{item}</td>
        <td><button onClick={e => handleDelete(index,e)}>Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <table>
        {rows}
        </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use hook `useState` to save your data and after that with `handlerDelete` remove the element and set the data. React will re-render component (because your state has been changed) and you get necessary result:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-surf-iykn7?file=/src/App.js